# Javascript dragging object

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

I need to make one div draggable and sets it's left position in according to mouse position.
I've searched a bit and this is what i have so far:

```
container = $('<div></div>').appendTo($('body')).addClass('container');

someText = $('<div>Some text</div>').appendTo(container);

slider = $('<div></div>').appendTo(container);
slider.addClass('slider');

var isDragging = false;
slider.on('mousedown', function () {
    isDragging = true;
});
$(window).on('mouseup', function () {
    console.log('mouseup');
    isDragging = false;
});
container.on('mouseleave', function () {
    console.log('mouseleave');
    isDragging = false;
});
container.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (isDragging) {
        var newLeft = parseInt((e.pageX - container.offset().left), 10);
        console.log(newLeft);
        slider.css('left', newLeft);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9gxxuvw/2/

The white box is one which should be draggable, but there are a few drawbacks.
First of all, while i drag with my LPM down i select upper text.
Secondly, on chrome when i drag it fast, it doesn't fire mouse up event, so 'slider' just follows cursor while it's moving inside 'container' and i need to click somewhere to stop.

It's not necessary for me to use jQuery, but i don't won't to use another big framework nor jquery plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent text selection with the [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) CSS property:

```js
container = $('<div></div>').appendTo($('body')).addClass('container');

someText = $('<div>Some text</div>').appendTo(container);

slider = $('<div></div>').appendTo(container);
slider.addClass('slider');

var isDragging = false;

slider.on('mousedown', function () {
  isDragging = true;
});

$(window).on('mouseup', function () {
  isDragging = false;
});

container.on('mouseleave', function () {
  isDragging = false;
});

container.on('mousemove', function (e) {
  if (isDragging) {
    var newLeft = parseInt((e.pageX - container.offset().left), 10);
    slider.css('left', newLeft);
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
    display:block;
    width:400px;
    height:100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.slider {
    display:block;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    background: #fff;
    position:relative;
    left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot reproduce the problem of the draggable sticking to the mouse in Chrome 42, Firefox 36 or Safari 7. Above example runs flawlessly for me.

Comment: Another bug with dragging was fixed while you used another version of jQuery. Thanks

Comment: @PiotrŁużecki self-fixing bugs are the best kind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Preventing the default action for text selection in the script seems more logical, it has deeper support than CSS `user-select` as well. Since (most of) the events are connected in this function, I'd nest them. It'll allow for a bit of optimisation. It also makes sense to unbind the mousemove, after several events you may generally start to notice sluggish behaviour otherwise.

```
...

container.on('mousedown', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
});

slider.on('mousedown', function() {

$(window).one('mouseup', function() {
console.log('mouseup');
container.off('mousemove');
});

container.on('mousemove', function(e) {
var newLeft = Math.round(e.pageX-container.offset().left);
console.log(newLeft);
slider.css('left', newLeft);
})
.one('mouseleave', function() {
console.log('mouseleave');
container.off('mousemove');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9gxxuvw/8/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't affect performance in my end application. And i will stay with css

Comment: No problem, can never hurt to add some extra info. Nesting the events really is a better approach than using the variable though. And unbinding mousemoves especially is always a good idea.